# 複数のグローバル変数をevalを使わず動的にlocalすることは可能ですか？

Tags: perl

グローバルな変数`$foo`, `$bar`, `$buz`が存在し、それらを特定のスコープ内のみ局所化しようとすると、以下のようになると思います:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

our ($foo, $bar, $buz) = qw(foo bar buz);

UPPER_CASE_WORLD: {
    # このスコープだけ所定のグローバル変数を大文字に
    no strict 'refs';
    local ($foo, $bar, $buz) = map { uc ${"::$_"} } qw(foo bar buz);

    say $foo, $bar, $buz;
}

say $foo, $bar, $buz;

1;
```

これを「不特定多数のグローバル変数」に拡張した時、forループをそのまま使うとforの外に局所化した変数を出せません。

```
    # 不特定多数のグローバル変数を大文字に
    no strict 'refs';
    my @globals = qw(foo bar buz);
    local ${"::$_"} = uc ${"::$_"} for @globals;

    # がっ...駄目っ...forの外！
    say $foo, $bar, $buz;
```

仕方なく`eval`に頼ると、ブロックそのものを食わせる必要がありそうです。ちょっと無理矢理感があります。

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

our ($foo, $bar, $buz) = qw(foo bar buz);

no strict 'refs';
my @globals = qw(foo bar buz);
my $bunch_of_locals = join q{}, map {
    "local \${'::$_'} = uc \${'::$_'};"
} @globals;

eval <<"__UPPER_CASE_WORLD";
{
    # 不特定多数のグローバル変数を大文字に
    $bunch_of_locals

    # ここまでしなきゃいけない？
    say \$foo, \$bar, \$buz;
}
__UPPER_CASE_WORLD

say $foo, $bar, $buz;

1;
```

このような不特定多数のグローバル変数をあるスコープで局所化したい場合、`eval`を使わずにすんなり書く事はできないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

例えば次のような感じでどうでしょうか。
コンセプトはスコープの最初に値を保存し終了時に戻す。（つまり手動local)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

our ($foo, $bar, $buz) = qw(foo bar buz);

#糖衣構文用関数
sub using(&@) {
    my $code = shift;
    my @v = @_;#変数の内容を保存
    $code->(@_);
    my $i = 0;
    $_ = $v[$i++] for @_;#変数の内容を復元
}

using {
    $_ = uc  $_  for @_;
    say $foo, $bar, $buz;#内容が変更された(大域)変数、大文字で表示される。
} $foo, $bar, $buz;#不特定の可変個の引数

say $foo, $bar, $buz;
```